# PGFplots: force thicks labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I need your help. my ticks labels are inside the graph but I need outside, please, help me. my code is:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
    \centering
    \begin{axis}[legend pos=south east, xmin=3300,xmax=580, xlabel=Número de onda (cm$ ^{-1} $), ymin=0.8, ymax=1, ylabel=Transmitancia (\%T), tick style={draw=none}]      
    %\addplot [color=red] table[col sep=comma]{dicloro.txt};
%   \addlegendentry{Blanco}
    \addplot [color=green] table[col sep=comma]{indigo.txt}; %THIS IS A TXT ARCHIVE OF DATES
    \addlegendentry{Índigo} 
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: You have `xmin=3300,xmax=580`, is that a typo? The max should be bigger than the min.

Comment: Please (for another time) make your code compilable. I do not know the meaning of "force thicks labels" - can you change the title?

Comment: xmin=3300,xmax=580 is correct for my spectrum but, I dont know how force outside thicks.

Comment: @Juliperezor A tip: when replying to comments, write `@<username>`, like I did here. You as the owner of the post are notified of all comments, but to make sure other users are notified use the at-symbol. You can only ping one user per comment, and only those who have commented on or edited the post. I only saw your reply by accident because I wasn't notified. By the way, it's "ticks", not "thicks". :)

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
xmin=3300, xmax=5800,
ymin=0.8, ymax=1, 
legend pos=south east,
xlabel=Número de onda (cm$ ^{-1} $), 
ylabel=Transmitancia (\%T),
tick style={thick, red},
tick align=outside,
tick pos=lower,
]      
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: empty graph with ticks outside]

Answer (score 1):

Having an `xmin` value that is larger than the `xmax` value is wrong I think, and probably the reason why the ticklabels are inside the axis.  To plot the x-values in descending order, which I guess is what you want to do, add `x dir=reverse` in addition to swapping `xmin` and `xmax`, so that `xmin` is the smallest numerical value.

In the code below I replaced your datafile with random numbers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    legend pos=south east,
    xmax=3300, % <- the largest value
    xmin=580, % <- the smallest value
    x dir=reverse, % <-- add this to flip the axis
    xlabel=Número de onda (cm$ ^{-1} $),
    ymin=0.8,
    ymax=1,
    ylabel=Transmitancia (\%T),
    tick style={draw=none}]      
    \addplot [color=green,domain=600:3200,samples=200] {abs(rnd)*0.2+0.8};
    \addlegendentry{Índigo} 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is probably the correct solution. -I was confused and only looked at the picture.